# How to convert Row to columns in SQL?

Tags: sql, rows

I am having a Table with TERMINAL_ID,Amount and Dates.I want the output as distinct Terminal ID,The distinct date as headers and sum of amount for that Terminal date wise.

I am using below Query but only getting Terminal ID in the Output but i want Dates a column heading and data as sum(TXN_AMT) for respective date

```
SELECT
    distinct([TERM_ID])
FROM Hitachi_tbl_May_22 Result
PIVOT (
  SUM([TXN_AMT])
  FOR [DATE]
  IN ("2022-05-01","2022-05-02")
) AS PivotTable;
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result? I think `PIVOT` might be right way

Comment: If you want the columns to appear in your results, they need to be in your select clause.   Such as `SELECT result.[Term_ID], pivottable.[2022-05-01], pivottable.[2022-05-02] FROM ...`  *(Also, `DISTINCT` isn't a function on a column, it doesn't work the way you think, and isn't necessary here.)*

Comment: Ideally, do it up in your report builder or whatever else is being used to present this data to human beings. Despite some superficial resemblances, SQL tables are *not* like spreadsheets. In spreadsheets, rows and columns are interchangeable. In SQL, they are very different things (E.g. all items in a column in SQL must have the same type, as one example)

Comment: Sample Data    Terminal_ID 01-05-2022 02-05-2022 03-05-2022
                                 A1             2,000.00   3                     40
                                    A2  2,000.00          3                    40
                                       A3  2,000.00         3                    40
I want the Output like this

Answer (score 0):

use this : For two column only if you use dynamic date then first find all
date and after get it with `IN()` and set Column

```
SELECT
    distinct([TERM_ID]),[2022-05-01],[2022-05-02]
FROM Hitachi_tbl_May_22 Result
PIVOT (
  SUM([TXN_AMT])
  FOR [DATE]
  IN ("2022-05-01","2022-05-02")
) AS PivotTable;
```

Comment: Thanks @Piyush Kachhadiya the query is getting executing but data for some days is showing null but for that date there are amounts when I checked individually for that Term_ID

Comment: that is work fine but you getting only two column that pass date in pivot, you need all date column then find first all column name after use it in pivoted.

Comment: @AdnanWadekar Do your data have time components stored in the date column? Replicate your issue on dbfiddle.uk and the copy the link here.

Comment: `DISTINCT` does ***not*** work like that, it is ***not*** a function... https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=89efeb5595351ce3658b69225e8b8a74

Comment: @MatBailie No only DATE the format it YYYY-MM-DD tired the below query with all the dates still the output is coming null only data for 1 date is getting shown not for all the dates Query is shared below

Comment: @Piyush Kachhadiya
Tired below query:SELECT
    distinct([TERM_ID]),[2022-05-01],[2022-05-02],[2022-05-03],[2022-05-04],[2022-05-05],[2022-05-06],[2022-05-07],
 [2022-05-08],[2022-05-09],[2022-05-10],[2022-05-11]
FROM Table_Name Result
PIVOT (
  SUM([TXN_AMT])
  FOR [DATE]
  IN ("2022-05-01","2022-05-02","2022-05-03","2022-05-04","2022-05-05","2022-05-06","2022-05-07","2022-05-08",
  "2022-05-09","2022-05-10","2022-05-11")
) AS PivotTable;

Comment: @Piyush Kachhadiya the query is working but the output is incorrect for instance there is a Terminal A12345 which has TXN amount for that day its showing null only for 1 day out of the remaining it is giving output rest NULL is coming

Comment: Please add sample data And expected output in your question so we can find out something.

Comment: @AdnanWadekar Please read as my comment again; I asked you to create an example on dbfiddle.uk but all you did is dump some code in a comment.